# The service has been enabled but failed. How can I make it run?

Tags: bash, service, scripting, systemd, linux-mint

I use Linux Mint 19. I have created a simple script, "After_suspension", which will run three commands. I am trying to make it run when Mint wakes up from suspension.

```
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ cat /usr/local/bin/After_suspension
#!/bin/bash
pon dsl-provider
sudo service fancontrol start
/usr/bin/mailnag

matthew@matthew-pc:~$ file /usr/local/bin/After_suspension
/usr/local/bin/After_suspension: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

"mailnag" is `(text/x-python)`. I have created the following service file, which has been enabled but failed. How can I make it run? Should I use three separate service files to run the three commands?

```
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/After_suspension.service
[Unit]
After=suspend.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/After_suspension

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ systemctl is-enabled After_suspension.service
enabled
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ systemctl is-active After_suspension.service
failed

matthew@matthew-pc:~$ systemctl status After_suspension.service
● After_suspension.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/After_suspension.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-11 01:19:42 HKT; 3min 46s ago
Process: 11655 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/After_suspension (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 11655 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 11 01:19:11 matthew-pc After_suspension[11655]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 122, in __new__
Apr 11 01:19:11 matthew-pc After_suspension[11655]:     bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
Apr 11 01:19:11 matthew-pc After_suspension[11655]: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbu
Apr 11 01:19:07 matthew-pc systemd[1]: Started 
After_suspension.service.
Apr 11 01:19:07 matthew-pc systemd[1]: After_suspension.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 11 01:19:42 matthew-pc pppd[11657]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Apr 11 01:19:42 matthew-pc pppd[11657]: Unable to complete PPPoE Discovery
Apr 11 01:19:42 matthew-pc pppd[11657]: Terminating on signal 15
Apr 11 01:19:42 matthew-pc pppd[11657]: Exit.
Apr 11 01:19:42 matthew-pc systemd[1]: After_suspension.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The following is the present "fancontrol.service".

```
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ cat /lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service
[Unit]
Description=fan speed regulator
# Run pwmconfig to create this file.
ConditionPathExists=/etc/fancontrol
After=lm-sensors.service
Documentation=man:fancontrol(8) man:pwmconfig(8)

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/fancontrol --check
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fancontrol
PIDFile=/var/run/fancontrol.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Systemd runs system scripts as root, so you're trying to start GNOME disks as a root, in a terminal session with no X server active, that's why you probably get a connection refused message.

You probably want to configure that service to be an user service (you'll probably have to pass the `DISPLAY` variable, too), or just first try setting a `DISPLAY` variable in either your script or systemd service.

Comment: @ icwebndev, I have edited my question. Please read it again. I actually aim to run three commands rather than start `GNOME Disks`. How should I modify the script file and/or the service file?

Comment: @MatthewWai I would avoid starting fan service from another service, since you can make an override. For other two, do they need to be run as root or as user?
If they have to be run as user, it would be much better to enable your After_suspension service for your user instead and see if it's working that way.

Comment: `sudo service fancontrol start` cannot be run without `sudo`, so I think it needs to be run as root. `/usr/bin/mailnag` can be run without `sudo`, so I think it can be run as a user. What should I do? How should the service file/script file be modified?

Comment: You can override fancontrol service (you can edit fancontrol service via `systemctl edit fancontrol.service`) to adjust it to run after `suspend.target`. 
As for your service, enable it as user service: `systemctl --user enable After_suspension.service`. To test if it's working, `systemctl --user start After_suspension.service`.
You have to disable system service first, of course.

Comment: I have added details about "fancontrol.service". Please read my question again. I want fancontrol to start at Linux startup and when Linux wakes from suspension. Should I create another service file for fancontrol?

Comment: No, just edit current one with `systemctl edit` and add `After` parameter for your target, it should be fine.

Comment: On another forum, someone has just helped me fixed the "fancontrol.service" problem. However, `pon dsl-provider` is not run and `/usr/bin/mailnag` is not running after Linux has woken from suspension. What should I do to make them run?